# C#(asp net mvc) -How to remove escape characters from string in controller or jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html-escape-characters

When I receive a string which has a special character in controller from an Ajax call, I see the following behaviour

```
string actualContent ="abc\efg";
```

The \ in the content is received as

```
string contentReceived ="abc\\efg";
```

What is the best way to remove the escaping character \ ? Either in controller while receiving this string or in jquery while post processing this.

Comment: Are you looking at that in debug? That's just string escaping if so and isn't really there

Answer (score 4):

So assuming that you might be receiving double slashes for one time or multiple times here in this case, you might as well use `Replace` function to just replace each and every occurrence of `\\` with a `\`. Something like this could help.

```
string receivedStr= "abc\\efg";
string actualStr = receivedStr.Replace("\\", "\");
```

Also, if its a URL type string, then it is normal to appear that way with double backslashes. If its some other kind of string, you need to work it out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the escape / unescape methods in the regex library.

eg 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape("abc\efg");
returns "abc\efg"

Very nice article here on its use http://www.dotnetperls.com/unescape